# How to use Range property properly?

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to copy like this.

[image: what I was thinking]

But, this is what I got

[image: Cell "D2" has problem]

My code is quite simple

```
Range("C1:C2, D1:D2").Value = Range("A1:A2").Value
```

I just want to copy several cells as a whole into several different places at once using Range propery like this.

Does it has something relationship with Order of Operation ? I mean between "Union Operator"(a Comma) and "Range Operator"(a Colon) within a Range property ?

Comment: `Range("C1:D2").Value = Range("A1:A2").Value` would work in this case.

Comment: @BigBen you type way too fast

Comment: `Range("C1:C2, D1:D2")` has two `Areas`. Writing into (or reading from) the `.Value` of a multi-area range in one step generally fails.

Comment: @BigBen Nice try. Unfortunately, some of my destination is not side-by-side, it has some distance between them.

Comment: The non Contiguous ranges will need to be done separately, Loop the `Areas` of the range.

Comment: Yes. Loop. That should be the final answer, I guess too. So.. You guys, the recommendation is try not to use mutilple destinations at once, in this case (in a single Range property) ?

Comment: Loop is necessary.  Which loop and how to use it depends greatly on your actual setup and desire.  There are many ways to do this, some quicker than others. Find what makes sense and works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Range("C1:C2, D1:D2")` is a multi-area range.

You need to loop over the `.Areas` of a multi-area range here:

```
Dim rng As Range
For Each rng in Range("C1:C2, D1:D2").Areas
   rng.Value = Range("A1:A2").Value
Next
```